# Plot() error when using REngine.Rserve

Tags: r, plot, rserve

I'm now work on a project which wants to use org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve to use facilities of R by C#. I have a particular problem that when I run the following code in C# client side:

```
c.eval("pdf(file=\"plots.pdf\", width=11, height=8.5)");
c.eval("plot(1,2)");
```

An error occour which said

```
Error in plot.new():cannot open file '', reason No such file or directory
```

But I checked that the file "plots.pdf" has already been created successfully by "pdf.." function. In R semantics, the successive plot() will output figure to the active device opened by the "pdf(...)" function, i.e. "plots.pdf" this time. But I'm very confused that why the error indicated that the file is ''.
I use R-2.15.0 and Rserve-1.7.0 in linux server side. 
I'm eager to see your response.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've just run into the problem, which looks exactly the same. Was just wondering if you had any chance on progressing on it?

Comment: I remember I solve this by restarting the Rserve engine and calling c.eval("dev.off()") each time after "pdf(...); plot(...)" statement. It seems that the error is caused by not closing the device correctly last time. If you still find some problem, you can try c.voidEval instead of c.eval. I found some r statement cannot run correctly in eval function. Hope my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
c.eval("dev.off()")
```

Comment: That is also mentioned in the comments, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

A folder named **`(null).1001.1001`**

---

Related answer at 
[Cannot open file '', reason No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798605/cannot-open-file-reason-no-such-file-or-directory#16798685)
suggests using `file.path` as a alternative to `paste` for creating filenames with platform-independent path separators.

Comments suggest `dev.off()`.  I had better luck with `graphics.off()`. The difference is that `dev.close()` closes the current device, `graphics.off()` closes all open devices.

But my solution turned out to be 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/721485/what-is-folder-null-1001-1001
I found a mysterious folder named `(null).1001.1001` (Rserve is running as uid 1001, gid 1001 on Linux). I create this folder at the start of my session and I'm good to go.  The presence of this folder seems to help in my case, but I don't know (yet!) what that folder is.