# Cannot open file '', reason No such file or directory

Tags: r, plot, rserve

I've run into the following problem, which *sometimes* happens when running the code in R under Rserve. So far I was unable to replicate this.

I first create a PDF with

```
pdf(file=paste(output.dir, "/dates_",name,".pdf",sep=""),width=6.25,height=9,title="Breakdown Dates:")
```

and then plot the data:

```
plot(time, data1, xlab="", ylab="")
```

Most of the time it works, when it fails I get the error:

> cannot open file '', reason No such file or directory

I've rerun this and debugged multiple times and all is working fine. However, sometimes in production it fails. Currently I suspect either the RServe or the file system perhaps.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: The evidence piles up to suggest it is a Rserve issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417454/plot-error-when-using-rengine-rserve

Answer (score 2):

`file.path` is more portable across file systems than `paste`, as it automatically sets appropriate directory separators.  Use `paste` (or `paste0`) for just the filename:

```
pdf(file=file.path(output.dir, paste0("dates_", name, ".pdf")), 
    width=6.25,height=9,title="Breakdown Dates:")
```

Comment: Good point, thanks Noam. I don't think this is the reason why this particular code fails though as it always runs on the same Linux machine.