# Error in plot.new() when creating PDF in R

Tags: r, pdf, dendrogram

When plotting a dendrogram in R, I get a funny error that I've never seen before.

```
Error in plot.new() : 
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\Sun\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpKSRNuD\pdf12207aa37548', reason No such file or directory
```

I didn't have that error yesterday when plotting other dendrograms and saving it in PDF files .. Any idea what it means?

Comment: Need the code....  And did you do this after saving an `.RData` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Related answer at [Plot() error when using REngine.Rserve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417454/plot-error-when-using-rengine-rserve) suggests sending a `dev.close()` call as a workaround for "not closing the device correctly last time" (specifically under Rserve).

Related answer at [Cannot open file '', reason No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798605/cannot-open-file-reason-no-such-file-or-directory) suggests using `file.path` as a alternative to `paste` for creating filenames with platform-independent path separators.

I'm having better luck with [`graphics.off()`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/grDevices/dev.off).  The difference is that `dev.close()` closes the current device, `graphics.off()` closes all open devices.  In my case, I'm writing a PDF inside a knitr Rmd called from an Rserve session, so I may have multiple open devices.

I'm also finding that there's a [mysterious folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34883386/what-is-folder-null-1001-1001) named `(null).1001.1001` (it's on an Ubuntu box, logged in as uid 1001, gid 1001).  The presence of this folder seems to help in my case.

Comment: Thanks for accepting this answer.  Which observation was the most helpful?

Comment: This should be broken up into multiple answers as per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314022/how-to-deal-with-multiple-answers-in-the-same-answer