# What is folder (null).1001.1001

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, uid, cifs, rserve

### (null).1001.1001

What is this folder?  Where does it come from?

```
drwxrwxrwx 49 appusr    appusr    4096 Jan  7 21:52 (null).1001.1001
```

I think it has something to do with Mr. Root impersonating Mr. AppUsr in a background task, but I posted to AskUbuntu last week, and nobody there recognized it.

---

Why am I asking?  Well ...

On an `Ubuntu` box, I have a restricted-access applications user who is uid **1001** and gid **1001**.  Root launches `Rserve` under that user during boot.  The `Rserve` session is writing into a Windows `CIFS` share.  All seems to be functioning as intended ...

I'm finding these folders peppered throughout the application user's file tree:

```
drwxrwxrwx 49 appusr    appusr    4096 Jan  7 21:52 (null).1001.1001
```

I'm finding these subfolders in various folders.  Each of these subfolders is different, but they seem to contain partial temporary files, like stuff that I extracted from a tarball, or partial pdf writes.

My primary interest in these folders is that I've found that sometimes I need them and don't have them.  There's a particular operation can work or fail depending on whether or not this folder is present.  When writing a PDF from inside a `knitr` document that I call remotely from `Rserve`, I get this error message

[`## Error in plot.new(): cannot open file '', reason No such file or directory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417454/plot-error-when-using-rengine-rserve)

I can't find an R reason for this, and it works when called from an `rstudio-server` session or from a Windows `Rstudio` IDE, but when called from `Rserve`, it seems to depend on having that folder present in the filesystem, and I'm quite sure that I didn't put it there!  What is it?

Comment: I see that you got no attention to your question on askbuntu... nonetheless, I think that's a better place for it than here on SO. http://askubuntu.com/questions/721485/what-is-folder-null-1001-1001

Comment: I'm not absolutely sure that it's an ubuntu question.